# Динамическое обновление data в vue.js

Tags: javascript, arduino, localstorage, vue.js

Есть плата Arduino с датчиком температуры, которая через IoT PubNub при изменении температуры отправляет данные .
Скрипт записывает данные с датчика температуры в local storage, а потом отображает их через Vue Js. 
Скажите пожалуйста, можно ли сделать так, что бы динамически отображались актуальные данные которые приходят с датчика каждую секунду. А не те, что были в local storage на момент загрузки страницы. Я только учусь, прошу не минусовать.

```js
var pubnub = new PubNub({
    subscribeKey: "",
    publishKey: ""
});
var channel = "weather-channel";

pubnub.addListener({ //Listener for current temperature from arduino
    message: function(m) {
        localStorage.setItem("temperature data", JSON.stringify(m.message.temperature));
    }
});

console.log("subscribing..."); //Subscribing for channel
pubnub.subscribe({
    channels: [channel],
});

var app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        temperature: localStorage.getItem("temperature data")
    },

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue" charset="utf-8"></script> <!--Vue CDN -->
    <script src="https://cdn.pubnub.com/sdk/javascript/pubnub.4.8.0.js"></script> <!--PubNub CDN -->
    <title>control</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
<span>{{temperature}}</span>
</div>
</body>
    <script src="vue.js" charset="utf-8"></script> <!-- Client app js -->
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто обновлять свойство.
MVVM сам подхватит изменения и отобразит их.

```
...
pubnub.addListener({ //Listener for current temperature from arduino
  message: function(m) {
    app.temperature = JSON.stringify(m.message.temperature));
....
```

P. S. Советую сменить ключи, они в истории правок сохранены.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Я уже от безнадёги сделал через setInterval. У меня не всегда мозг работает в нужную сторону. Да. и про ключи - спасибо. Я не заметил когда постил, а теперь уже поздно.